# Convert quote to order generating empty order

Tags: magento-1, onepage-checkout, sales-order, payment, quote

I'm changing the Magento to not save automatically orders as pending at checkout. I want to save only orders that were paid, and if it fails back to the cart with an error message in the payment.

I got the Magento not save the order as pending, but now need to save as complete in case of success. So I'm trying to save the quote with the code below.

```
    $convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');

    $quoteModelInstance = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $customerModelInstance = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $paymentModelInstance = $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteModelInstance->getPayment());

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $order->setQuote($quoteModelInstance);
    $order->setCustomer($customerModelInstance);
    $order->setPayment($paymentModelInstance);
    $order->setShipping($customerModelInstance->getShippingRelatedInfo());

    try {
        $order->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
```

On **$quoteModelInstance** variable I have:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 1587
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2015-02-23 18:58:43
    [updated_at] => 2015-02-24 11:19:30
    [converted_at] => 
    [is_active] => 1
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [is_multi_shipping] => 0
    [items_count] => 1
    [items_qty] => 50.0000
    [orig_order_id] => 0
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
    [store_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_currency_code] => BRL
    [store_currency_code] => BRL
    [quote_currency_code] => BRL
    [grand_total] => 1.0000
    [base_grand_total] => 1.0000
    [checkout_method] => 
    [customer_id] => 10
    [customer_tax_class_id] => 3
    [customer_group_id] => 1
    [customer_email] => eduardo@hefer.com.br
    [customer_prefix] => 
    [customer_firstname] => Eduardo
    [customer_middlename] => 
    [customer_lastname] => Dias
    [customer_suffix] => 
    [customer_dob] => 1991-02-24 00:00:00
    [complemento] => 
    [numero] => 
    [bairro] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [customer_is_guest] => 0
    [remote_ip] => 177.64.172.10
    [applied_rule_ids] => 1
    [reserved_order_id] => 
    [password_hash] => 
    [coupon_code] => 
    [global_currency_code] => BRL
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
    [customer_taxvat] => 
    [customer_gender] => 1
    [subtotal] => 1.0000
    [base_subtotal] => 1.0000
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 1.0000
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 1.0000
    [is_changed] => 1
    [trigger_recollect] => 0
    [ext_shipping_info] => 
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [is_persistent] => 0
    [interest] => 
    [base_interest] => 
    [agillitas_vet] => 0.0200
    [x_forwarded_for] => 
)
```

And in **$quoteModelInstance->getPayment()**:

```
Array
(
    [payment_id] => 295
    [quote_id] => 1587
    [created_at] => 2015-02-24 11:18:58
    [updated_at] => 2015-02-24 11:19:27
    [method] => Query_Cielo_Dc
    [cc_type] => visa
    [cc_number_enc] => 
    [cc_last4] => 
    [cc_cid_enc] => 
    [cc_owner] => 
    [cc_exp_month] => 11
    [cc_exp_year] => 2023
    [cc_ss_owner] => 
    [cc_ss_start_month] => 0
    [cc_ss_start_year] => 0
    [po_number] => 
    [additional_data] => 
    [cc_ss_issue] => 
    [additional_information] => Array
        (
        )

    [paypal_payer_id] => 
    [paypal_payer_status] => 
    [paypal_correlation_id] => 
)
```

This generated the request, but did not save all the data, see image below.
[image: Wrong order id and empty order data]

I tried this way too:

```
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');
    $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());

    $order = $convert->toOrder($quote);
    $order->save();
```

But returned this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a
>   non-object in
>   /public/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

---

**EDIT 1:**
I got to save the order with this code:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->collectTotals()
    ->getPayment()->setMethod('purchaseorder');

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();
$order->save();
```

If I use another method of payment which has form, I lose the data. I need to get the data placed by the customer on payment method.

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: facing same issue

Answer (score 4):

One general remark here: You're trying to set the full customer session object (`Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')`) as the quote's customer. You should do `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()`.

As for the whole process, I have been doing this in the past as follows:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->assignCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());

$quote->collectTotals()
    ->getPayment()->setMethod('purchaseorder');

$convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');
$order = $convert->toOrder($quote)
    ->setBillingAddress(
        $convert->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getBillingAddress())
    )
    ->setShippingAddress(
        $convert->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getShippingAddress())
    )
    ->setPayment(
        $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment())
    );

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
    $orderItem = $convert->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem);
    if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
        $orderItem->setParentItem(
            $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getParentItem()->getId())
        );
    }
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->save();
```

I'm manually setting the payment method on the quote to `'purchaseorder'`. You should see if this works for you too and/or fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But still did not work, when I call $order->addItem($orderItem); the page turns blank. No logs or exception generated. I tried to surround with try and exception too. when I comment the foreach and try to save the order the following error appears: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (db_comprandofora_dev.sales_flat_order_payment, CONSTRAINT FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_PAYMENT_PARENT_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES sales_flat_order (`entit)

Comment: I changed the payment form to Query_Cielo_Dc. But did not affect the error.

Answer (score 1):

For it's proper working, you need to assign the Customer as well. So the answer is basically a mix between both answers:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->assignCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
$quote->collectTotals()->getPayment()->setMethod('payment_method');
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();

$order = $service->getOrder();
$order->save();
```